# vbscript error 800A004C

Tags: vbscript

i need to create a text file named "**listfile.txt**" in the folder **C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application 
Data\netapp\system** so i did the following vbscript to acheive that

```
Const CommonAppData = &H23&  ' the second & denotes a long integer '
Const OSCPATH = "\netapp\system"
Dim fso, MyFile

Set objShell  = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(CommonAppData)

Set objFolderItem = objFolder.Self

'MsgBox objFolderItem.Name & ": " & objFolderItem.Path


Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set MyFile = fso.CreateTextFile("objFolderItem.Path & OSCPATH\listfile.txt", True)
MyFile.WriteLine("This is a test.")
MyFile.Close
```

but its throwing errors mentioning path is not found

### **Windows Script Host

Script: C:\Documents and Settings\puthuprf\Desktop\test.vbs
Line:   15
Char:   1
Error:  Path not found
Code:   800A004C

### Source:     Microsoft VBScript runtime error

OK
---------------------------**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line in your script is incorrect:

```
Set MyFile = fso.CreateTextFile("objFolderItem.Path & OSCPATH\listfile.txt", True)
```

To insert variables and object properties into a string, you need to concatenate them using the `&` operator, like this:

```
Set MyFile = fso.CreateTextFile(objFolderItem.Path & OSCPATH & "\listfile.txt", True)
```

Note that it is recommended to use the [`BuildPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0z2z1zt.aspx) method to combine multiple parts of the path, as it frees you from adding the necessary path separators (`\`) manually:

```
strFileName = fso.BuildPath(objFolderItem.Path, OSCPATH)
strFileName = fso.BuildPath(strFileName, "listfile.txt")

Set MyFile = fso.CreateTextFile(strFileName, True)
```

Comment: thats great Helen,,its works fine,,i am new to vbscript thats why,Thanks you for your help