# VB Script error 800a004c - when trying to access network drive

Tags: vbscript

Im really new to VB script and have run into a problem. I keep getting

> Error: Path not found
>   Code: 800A004C

when running the script;

```
Set objMachineList = objFSO.OpenTextFile(txtMachineList, ForReading)
```

If I change it to a local folder I no longer get the error but it needs to access the network drive for the script to work properly. Now time for the background story. There is a host computer that has the program (called TOMART, which are technical docs that are PDF with a GUI interface) installed to the network drive, with multiple computers accessing the drive (either online or always available offline) for sync purposes, which works fine. But the updates for the said program need to be installed into each of the networked computers hard drive for it to integrate and apply the updates for use with the program. The problem is, the updates need to be transferred to each computers hard drive for the program to recognise it and without the script working properly the updates arent getting transfered to each computers hard drive, so when accessing the updated PDFs in the program, the program just throws up error codes. I have attached the entire script in the hope someone here can help me out.

Sorry for the long winded description and apologies in advance if I haven't been clear with anything.

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.fileSystemObject")
Set objNet = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

ServerName = "\\Mynetworkdrivename\Files"
ETool = objNet.computerName
updateServer = "\\" & ServerName & "\TOMART\Update\"
txtMachineList = "\\" & ServerName & "\TOMART\Machines.txt"
txtLogFile = "\\" & ServerName & "\TOMART\Logs\" & ETool & ".txt"
localTOMARTUpdate = "C:\TOMART\update\"

Set objMachineList = objFSO.OpenTextFile(txtMachineList, ForReading)

Do While objMachineList.AtEndOfStream = False
  strLine = objMachineList.ReadLine
  If ETool = strLine THEN
     Set updServerList = objFSO.GetFolder(updateServer)
     Set colSubFlds = updServerList.SubFolders
     For Each fl in colSubFlds
subFldr = fl.name
If Not objFSO.folderExists _
     (localTOMARTUpdate & subFldr) THEN
     objFSO.copyFolder updateServer & subFldr, localTOMARTUpdate
End If
     Next
     Set textFile = objFSO.createTextFile(txtLogFile)
 End If
Loop
```

Comment: Try `Debug.Print txtMachineList` and check for the number of `\\` in the output

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vbscript error 800A004C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093204/vbscript-error-800a004c)

Comment: @Robin it's VBScript equivalent would be `WScript.Echo txtMachineList`, will output differently depending on whether they are using `cscript.exe` or `wscript.exe`.

Comment: You definitely need to check `txtMachineList`. From the code you are posting, you can concatenating `\\\`` and `\\\Mynetworkdrivename\Files` and `\TOMART\Machines.txt` which gives you `\\\\Mynetworkdrivename\Files\TOMART\Machines.txt`